# Splitting several PDB files into chains and save as separate files

Tags: python, biopython, pdb

I am trying to split a large number of pdb files using Biopython and then save them as separate files called pdbid_chain.pdb . So far I did not succeed. Additionally, I am quite new to python.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
#pdb_list contains a list of 208 pdb structures 

io = PDBIO()
     
#parse structures
for f in pdb_list:
    pdb_parsed = PDBParser().get_structure(pdb_ids, str(PDB_RAW_DIR) + '/' + f)
    
#save chains
for structure in pdb_parsed:
        pdb_chains = structure.get_chains()
        for chain in pdb_chains:
            io.set_structure(chain)
            io.save(pdb_parsed.get_id() + "_" + chain.get_id() + ".pdb")
```

Cheers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use MDAnalysis and use the selection algebra to select different chains.

Here is a simple example. The complex.pdb contains two chains A and I. Two new pdb files are created in which the chains are separated.

```
import MDAnalysis

# Import the pdb file as universe
u = MDAnalysis.Universe('complex.pdb')

# select chain A as receptor
receptor = u.select_atoms("chainID A")

# select chain I as ligand
ligand = u.select_atoms("chainID I")

# Save separated files as pdb
receptor.write("receptor.pdb")
ligand.write("ligand.pdb")
```